# horizontally moving jquery mobile popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, popup

I am relatively new to jquery-mobile. I am using jquery-mobile popup in my mobile site. I want to make popup can be moved horizontally.

I am using basic popup of jquery-mobile like -

```
<a href="#popupBasic" data-rel="popup">Open Popup</a>

<div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">
    <p>This is a completely basic popup, no options set.<p>
</div>
```

I have tried to search in jquery-mobile demos and tutorials but could not found anything.

Is there any way, with which this can be achived?

Comment: elaborate on "_move horizontally_".

Comment: The popup opened here should be draggable horizontally so that the user can move it to one of the side and see the screen behind the popup.